# Arrange gt tables side by side or in a grid or table of tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I'd like to generate a set of `gt` table objects in a grid or side-by-side. For example, the code below uses the `group_by` argument to *vertically* separate them. But what if I wanted them separated side-by-side?

```r
mtcars2 <-
  mtcars %>% 
  mutate(good_mpg = ifelse(mpg > 20, "Good mileage", "Bad mileage"), 
         car_name = row.names(.)) 

mtcars2 %>% 
  group_by(good_mpg) %>% 
  slice_max(order_by = hp, n=5) %>% 
  arrange(hp) %>% 
  select(car_name, hp) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(columns = c("hp"), 
             colors = col_numeric(palette = "Blues", 
                                  domain = c(0, 400)))
```

[image: table with vertical group_by]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Daniel, thank you for sharing this! This can come in handy.

To make the code a little bit more compact you could use `group_map` (or `do`) to generate the two tables within the `dplyr` workflow, then join them as you did:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(scales)

hp_table <- function(x){
    gt(x) %>% 
        data_color(columns="hp", 
                   colors=col_numeric(palette="Blues", c(0, 400))) %>% 
        tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE) %>% 
        as_raw_html()
}

mtcars %>% 
    mutate(good_mpg = ifelse(mpg > 20, "Good mileage", "Bad mileage"), 
           car_name = row.names(.))  %>% 
    arrange(hp) %>% 
    group_by(relevel(factor(good_mpg), "Good mileage")) %>% 
    slice_head(n=5) %>% 
    select(car_name, hp) %>%
    group_map(~ hp_table(.x)) %>% 
    data.frame(.) %>% 
    setNames(., c("High mileage", "Low mileage")) %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    fmt_markdown(columns = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using `as_raw_html()` for the internal tables, and `fmt_markdown(columns = TRUE)` in the top-level table.

```r
hp_table <- function(x){
  gt(x) %>% 
    data_color(columns = c("hp"), 
               colors = col_numeric(palette = "Blues", 
                                    domain = c(0, 400))) %>% 
    tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE) %>% 
    as_raw_html() # return as html
}

good_mpg_table <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  mutate(good_mpg = ifelse(mpg > 20, "Good mileage", "Bad mileage"), 
         car_name = row.names(.)) %>% 
  filter(good_mpg == "Good mileage") %>%
  head(5) %>% 
  arrange(hp) %>% 
  select(car_name, hp) %>% 
  hp_table()

bad_mpg_table <- 

  filter(good_mpg == "Bad mileage") %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  arrange(hp) %>% 
  select(car_name, hp) %>% 
  hp_table() 

data_tables <- data.frame(good_table = good_mpg_table, 
                          bad_table = bad_mpg_table)

data_tables %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_markdown(columns = TRUE) %>% #render cell contents as html
  cols_label(good_table = "High mileage", 
             bad_table = "Low mileage")
```

[image: Side-by-side tables]

Comment: Is there a way to include sub-table labels?  I notice that `tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE)` seems necessary to avoid some raw html in the resulting parent table.

Comment: Is there a way to print the column headings of individual tables too?