# Side-by-Side gt tables **WITH** footnotes

Tags: html, markdown, gt

I am trying to create side-by-side gt tables, as the title suggests. I started with the very helpful answer found here: [Arrange gt tables side by side or in a grid or table of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835639/arrange-gt-tables-side-by-side-or-in-a-grid-or-table-of-tables). The key was to ouput the left and right tables as raw html (as_raw_html), then combine in a dataframe, then send back into gt and reformat as markdow (fmt_markdown).

However, I ran into a problem that I couldn't solve. The fmt_markdown command skips the footnote, so the resulting table has the raw html as a footnote.

I checked the documentation for gt, and the fmt_markdown command takes **columns** and **rows** as input - but, apparently, the **footnote** area is considered neither a column nor a row.

So the crux seems to be that I can't seem to find any way to target the footnote area for reformatting as mardown.

Below is a reproducible example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

# Make a table with a footnote
tL <- exibble %>%
  select(c(num, char, group)) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = html("**I'm an apricot**"),
    locations = cells_body(columns = char,
                           rows = char == "apricot")
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_text(color = "blue"),
            locations = cells_footnotes()) %>% 
  as_raw_html()

# Make a copy
tR <- tL

# Side-By-Side
SideBySide <- data.frame(Ltable = tL, Rtable = tR) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: note: the gtsummary package can do this sort of operation with its tbl_merge function