# R - Add line breaks (subrows) in a dataframe

Tags: r, icons, line-breaks, gt, mutate

I want to add line breaks within a row for certain conditions

```
Test <- structure(list(A1 = c("SP2", "SP1"), A2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_
), B1 = c("AP2", "HN2"), B2 = c("HN2", "IP2"), B3 = c("HP2", 
"KN2"), B4 = c("IN2", "KP2"), B5 = c("JN2", "NP2"), B6 = c("KN2", 
"RN2"), B7 = c("KP2", "SN2"), B8 = c("NP2", "TP2"), B9 = c("RN2", 
"AP1"), B10 = c("SN2", "FP1")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

Test
   A1   A2  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9 B10
1 SP2 <NA> AP2 HN2 HP2 IN2 JN2 KN2 KP2 NP2 RN2 SN2
2 SP1 <NA> HN2 IP2 KN2 KP2 NP2 RN2 SN2 TP2 AP1 FP1
```

Every entry is a code to an icon, which I implemented with gt table.

```
Test %>% 
  gt() %>%
  #tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE) %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(columns = 1:length(Test)),
    fn = function(x) {
      # loop over the elements of the column
      map_chr(x, ~ local_image(
        filename = paste0(.x, ".png"),
        height = 15))})
```

That ends in this:

[image]

My question is now:
How can I add a line break when there are more than 3 columns starting with the same letter? My result should be the same for A1 und A2, but B1:B10 should consist of 4 "subrows", so the first 3 columns B1:B3 stay but then B4:B6 should be under B1:B3 and the same with B7:B9, and B10 stands alone in subrow 4.

So my desired output would be:

[image]

I know that a combination of `Test %>% mutate`, `"<br>"` and `fmt_markdown` might be right, but I cant find a working solution. The spacing is important, I want that each Group in each row is close together and clearly separated from the other groups.

Can someone help please? The link to download the icons I used is here:
[ICONS](https://file.io/UxnYhCaZ8wmP)

They are from this website: [iconscout.com](https://iconscout.com/icon-pack/typography)

Comment: What you're essentially doing here is creating two 3-column tables from vector data, then embedding those in an overarching table.  As such this might be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835639/arrange-gt-tables-side-by-side-or-in-a-grid-or-table-of-tables

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this and tell if I find a solution.

Comment: the icons file has been deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to the images, but the following should work:

```
Test <- Test %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(row = as.character(row_number())) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = "col", values_to = "val") %>% # split col into two columns, letter and index
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% # remove NA values
  mutate(letter = str_extract(col, "[A-Z]"), # extract letter
         index = str_extract(col, "[0-9]")) %>% # extract index
  select(-col) %>% 
  group_by(row, letter) %>% 
  arrange(index) %>% 
  mutate(val = paste(val, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-index) %>% 
  distinct()  %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = letter, values_from = val) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace_all(., "(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+", "\\1<br>"))) %>%
select(-row) 
# then replace the codes with the images here

Test %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
```

[image: table with two columns, A and B, with various codes]